# How do I delete the cell content in front of cell that have not been checked?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox

I have cell range. First column have content. Second column have check box. See first picture.[image: first picture]
I try to clear content Infront of unchecked boxes.

```
function clearCon() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp;
 var sheet =ss.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("AddData");     
 var chkVal = sheet.getRange("A29:B33").getValues();
 Logger.log(chkVal);
 Logger.log(chkVal.length);    
 for(var i=0; i<=chkVal.length; i++){
  if(chkVal[i][1] == false){
    Logger.log(i);
    sheet.getRange(28,1,i+1,1).clearContent();
    return;
   }
  }  
 }
```

See this picture [image: code]
it's not correctly work. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Description

First your script and picture of script don't match, so I'm not sure which one you are currently using.

Second, your for loop should be `i<chkval.length`.

Third, there should not be a return in your for loop.

Fourth, your `sheet.getRange(29+i, 1).clearContent()`

And lastly, if there are no formulas in the range you specified I would use setValues() as shown below.

Script

```
function clearCon() {
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName ("AddData");
    var chkval = sheet.getRange("A29:B33").getValues();
    // test for true or false
    chkval.forEach( row => row[0] = row[1] ? row[0] : '' );
    // extract column A
    chkval = chkval.map( row => row.slice(0,1) );
    console.log(chkval);
    sheet.getRange(29,1,chkval.length,1).setValues(chkval);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

References

- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices

Comment: picture is correct. I am copy from picture use google lens.

Answer (score 0):

You are only clearing the row 28 with your current code because you of `sheet.getRange(28, 1, …)`. So in your forward loop, you are not moving down the rows. To fix this issue, just do `sheet.getRange(29+i,1).clearContent()`.

Comment: When there is a "return" only the first one is clear. When I remove "return" I will get an error message as "TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined".